# Better way to get an unique object out of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with objects. Each object got an unique id. What is the best way to get a specific object from the array?

Currently I use something like this

```
  this.getObjectById = function(objectId){
    return $.grep(this.objects, function(e){ return e.id === objectId; })[0];
  }
```

but the fact that

```
$.grep();
```

returns an array of results I don't know if I should go for this. Because currently I take the first element of this array and it's fine because I just got one element in it.

But is there a more clean way?

Is

```
Array.prototype.find()
```

a better one?

Comment: When it comes to worst case complexity they're both the same. The `.find` is probably better if the result is closer to the start of the array.

Comment: Worth noting that `Array.prototype.find` doesn't work in IE so you would need to use the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find is faster since it returns the first match, while jquery grep loops trough entire array. If you need full browser support just create you own function:

```
this.getObjectById = function(objectId){
  for(var i = 0; i<this.objects.length; i++){
    if(objectId == this.objects[i].id) return this.objects[i];
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) _.find() method to iterate your collection.